# In C, how do I make sure that a memory load is performed only once?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I am programming two processes that communicate by posting messages to each other in a segment of shared memory. Although the messages are not accessed atomically, synchronization is achieved by protecting the messages with shared atomic objects accessed with store-releases and load-acquires.

My problem is about security. The processes do not trust each other. Upon receiving a message, a process makes no assumption about the message being well formed; it first copies the message from shared memory to private memory, then performs some validation on this private copy and, if valid, proceeds to handle this same private copy. Making this private copy is crucial, as it prevents a TOC/TOU attack in which the other process would modify the message between validation and use.

My question is the following: does the standard guarantee that a clever C compiler will never decide that it can read the original instead of the copy? Imagine the following scenario, in which the message is a simple integer:

```
int private = *pshared; // pshared points to the message in shared memory
...
if (is_valid(private)) {
  ...
  handle(private);
}
```

If the compiler runs out of registers and temporarily needs to spill `private`, could it decide, instead of spilling it to the stack, that it can simply discard its value and reload it from `*pshared` later, provided that an alias analysis ensures that *this thread* has not changed `*pshared`?

My guess is that such a compiler optimization would not preserve the semantics of the source program, and would therefore be illegal: `pshared` does not point to an object that is provably reachable from this thread only (such as an object allocated on the stack whose address has not leaked), therefore the compiler cannot rule out that some other thread might concurrently modify `*pshared`. By constrast, the compiler may eliminate redundant loads, because one of  the possible behaviors is that no other thread runs between the redundant loads, therefore the current thread must be ready to deal with this particular behavior.

Could anyone confirm or infirm that guess and possibly provide references to the relevant parts of the standard?

(By the way: I assume that the message type has no trap representations, so that loads are always defined.)

**UPDATE**

Several posters have commented on the need for synchronization, which I did not intend to get into, since I believe that I already have this covered. But since people are pointing that out, it is only fair that I provide more details.

I am implementing a low-level asynchronous communication system between two entities that do not trust each other. I run tests with processes, but will eventually move to virtual machines on top of a hypervisor. I have two basic ingredients at my disposal: shared memory and a notification mechanism (typically, injecting an IRQ into the other virtual machine).

I have implemented a generic circular buffer structure with which the communicating entities can produce messages, then send the aforementioned notifications to let each other know when there is something to consume. Each entity maintains its own private state that tracks what it has produced/consumed, and there is a shared state in shared memory composed of message slots and atomic integers tracking the bounds of the regions holding pending messages. The protocol unambiguously identifies which message slots are to be exclusively accessed by which entity at any time. When it needs to produce a message, an entity writes a message (non atomically) to the appropriate slot, then performs an atomic store-release to the appropriate atomic integer to transfer the ownership of the slot to the other entity, then waits until memory writes have completed, then sends a notification to wake up the other entity. Upon receiving a notification, the other entity is expected to perform an atomic load-acquire on the appropriate atomic integer, determine how many pending messages there are, then consume them.

The load of `*pshared` in my code snippet is just an example of what consuming a trivial (`int`) message looks like. In a realistic setting, the message would be a structure. Consuming a message does not need any particular atomicity or synchronization, since, as specified by the protocol, it only happens when the consuming entity has synchronized with the other one and knows that it owns the message slot. As long as both entites follow the protocol, everything works flawlessly.

Now, I do not want the entites to have to trust each other. Their implementation must be robust against a malicious entity that would disregard the protocol and write all over the shared memory segment at any time. If this were to happen, the only thing the malicious entity should be able to achieve would be to disrupt the communication. Think of a typical server, that must be prepared to handle ill-formed requests by a malicious client, without letting such misbehavior cause buffer overflows or out-of-bound accesses.

So, while the protocol relies on synchronization for normal operation, the entities must be prepared for the contents of shared memory to change at any time. All I need is a way to make sure that, after an entity makes a private copy of a message, it validates and uses that same copy, and never accesses the original any more.

I have an implementation that copies the message using a volatile read, thus making it clear to the compiler that the shared memory does not have ordinary memory semantics. I believe that this is sufficient; I wonder whether it is necessary.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple socket IPC instead of manage manually all those things?

Comment: Very good question! At least `pshared` should be qualified as `volatile` to tell compiler that it may be modified in other ways. I'm not sure any compiler would optimize `private` variable the way you suspect...

Comment: I don't think compiler can do that. Assuming that type of `pshared` is `int*`, compiler should solve the question *"Can `private` be modified through `*pshared`?"*. If not, then `private` could be stored in register. If yes, it still doesn't mean that compiler can assume that `private` **is** `*pshared`.

Comment: I added the "language-lawyer" tag, as it seems appropriate.  But if you distrust the data you copy that much, you also have to worry about compiler bugs and should probably be inspecting the actual instructions the compiler produces.

Comment: Can't you solve your problem using semaphores? It looks typically like something that can be solved using semaphores.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Inter-process synchronization is not covered by Standard C, so the language-lawyer tag is not really appropriate

Comment: @user694733: `private` and `*pshared` aren't "real" things, they're C abstractions. The fear here is that the compiler might compile "read from `private`" into a load from the shared memory region.

Comment: @M.M But his example is a single process loading an `int` value via a pointer.

Comment: @AndrewHenle it includes the condition that the `*shared` location may be altered by another process.

Comment: @M.M But that's the same as `volatile`.  And it seems to me the question then becomes, "In the absence of memory fences, is it allowable for the compiler to generate code that reloads a value after its value has been evaluated?"  I'm trying to give the benefit of the doubt here, as the wording of the question isn't really precise and the exact code isn't provided.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's not the same as `volatile`, and I am assuming OP does have a memory fence in the first `...` part

Answer (score 3):

You should inform the compiler the the shared memory can change at any moment by the `volatile` modifier.

```
volatile int *pshared;
...
int private = *pshared; // pshared points to the message in shared memory
...
if (is_valid(private)) {
  ...
  handle(private);
}
```

As `*pshared` is declared to be volatile, the compiler can no longer assume that `*pshared` and `private` keep same value.

---

Per your edit, it is now clear, that we all know that a volatile modifier on the shared memory is sufficient to guarantee that the compiler will honour the temporality of all accesses to that shared memory.

Anyway, draft N1256 for C99 is explicit about it in 5.1.2.3 Program execution (emphasize mine)

> 2 **Accessing a volatile object**, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function
>   that does any of those operations **are all side effects**, which are changes in the state of
>   the execution environment. Evaluation of an expression may produce side effects. At
>   certain specified points in the execution sequence called **sequence points, all side effects
>   of previous evaluations shall be complete and no side effects of subsequent evaluations
>   shall have taken place**.
>
> 5 The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>   — At sequence points, volatile objects are stable in the sense that previous accesses are
>   complete and subsequent accesses have not yet occurred
>   — At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that
>   execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.

That let think that even if `pshared` is not qualified as volatile, `private` value must have been loaded from `*pshared` before the evaluation of `is_valid`, and as the abstract machine has no reason to change it before the evaluation of `handle`, a conformant implementation should not change it. At most it could remove the call to `handle` if it contained no *side-effects* which is unlikely to happen

---

Anyway, this is only an academic discussion, because I cannot imagine a real use case where share memory could not need the `volatile` modifier. If you do not use it, the compiler is free to believe that the previous value is still valid, so on second access, you will still get first value. So even if the answer to *this* question is *it is not necessary*, you still have to use `volatile int *pshared;`.

Comment: Thanks, this actually is my current robust solution; I am just wondering if it is necessary.

Comment: @odelande: I think it is not necessary, see my edit.

Comment: I don't quite follow you. AFAIK, with C11 explicitly knowing about threads (at least on a hosted implementation), the compiler is _not_ free to believe that reloading memory will yield the value last written by the current thread. However, it is one of the possible behaviors, which the compiler is free to favor by removing duplicate reads _as long as there is no intermediate synchronization_; you do not need volatile if you perform some form of synchronization. In order to _prevent_ a reload, which is what I need, my guess is that you do not need volatile either.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question as posted. Note that you *must* use a synchronization object to prevent concurrent accesses, unless you are only reading units which are atomic on the platform.

I am assuming that you intend to ask about (pseudocode):

```
lock_shared_area();
int private = *pshared;
unlock_shared_area();

if (is_valid(private))
```

and that the other process also uses the same lock. (If not, it would be good to update your question to be a bit more specific about your synchronization).

This code guarantees to read `*pshared` at most once.  Using the name `private` means to read the variable `private`, not the object `*pshared`. The compiler "knows" that the call to unlock the area acts as a memory fence and it won't reorder operations past the fence.

Answer (score 0):

Since the C doesn't have any concept of interprocess communication there is nothing you can do to inform the compiler that there is another process that might be modifying the memory.

Thus, I believe there is no way to prevent a sufficiently clever, malicious, but conforming build system from invoking the "as if" rule to allow it to do the Wrong Thing.

To get something that is 'guaranteed' to work, you need to work whatever guarantees are given by your specific compiler and/or shared memory library you're using.

Comment: Note that C11 draft standard n1570 *does* have this to say about inter-process communication via atomics: *7.17.5 Lock-free property 2 NOTE Operations that are lock-free should also be address-free. That is, atomic operations on the same
memory location via two different addresses will communicate atomically. The implementation should not depend on any per-process state. This restriction enables communication via memory mapped into a process more than once and memory shared between two processes.* It's not a requirement, but it is a *should*.